# Prony method doesn't work

Tags: fft, python, power-spectral-density, scipy

I have used the code from: https://github.com/quantumlib/OpenFermion/blob/v1.5.1/src/openfermion/linalg/wave_fitting.py#L41-L76

try using with my signal:

```
def ns_s(t):
    if t >= 0 and t < 0.1:
      return 10*np.cos(20*np.pi*t)

    if t >= 0.1 and t <= 0.4:
      return 10*np.cos(20*np.pi*t)+3*np.sin(40*np.pi*t)
      
    if t > 0.4:
      return 0.0

def s_s(t):
  return 10*np.cos(20*np.pi*t)+3*np.sin(40*np.pi*t)+.01j

def s_old(x):
  return 3*np.sin(20.0*2.0*np.pi*x)+np.cos(50.0*2.0*np.pi*x)
```

FFT mag:

[image]

STFT mag:

[image]

Prony amplitudes:

[image]

What should I do to make it work? I tried complex signal but it doesn't work with it either (and fft, stft looks like random).

With stationary signal it's doesn't work also:

FFT:

[image]

Prony:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to our forum. Your code just defines 3 signals but doesn't show what you are specifically doing with them, what your expected result is, and why you think what you have is wrong.  Please add more detail and background.

Comment: I expected Prony results is close to FFT

Comment: What parameters you gave to the function you used.

Comment: @learner x = np.arange(0, np.pi/6, T)
y = np.array(list(map(ns_s, x)))

Comment: Your code doesn't show you calling a Prony solver.

Comment: @TimWescott amps, phases = prony(y) y is my signal

Comment: You need to _edit your question_ for details and clarity.  We cannot read your mind.  Please _add to your code_ to show how the stuff you're generating is used in the Prony solver, then _add discussion to your text_ to say what you're trying to do and how you believe it relates to Prony's method.